# servicio de windows creado desde visua studio no conecta con la base de datos

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, vb.net, servicio

He creado un servicio de `windows` con `visual studio 2022` que trabaja con un timer.

Lo que necesito es que el servicio  cada 24 tome datos de unas tablas de la BD y grabe en otras.

Si en el evento `elapsed` del `timer` (para hacer una prueba) escribo un código para que cree un archivo txt con un texto, lo hace perfectamente, lo que demuestra que el servicio funciona. Pero si pongo el código para que haga una select a una tabla de la base de datos o un insert no lo hace.

Probé de hacer un `try catch` con la conexion y en el `catch` pongo las lineas que crean el archivo de texto y el archivo se crea lo que me indica que no puede abrir la conexion y se va por el catch.

Si ese mismo código lo utilizo en un proyecto de `windows forms` funciona perfectamente, se conecta, hace la `select` y el `insert` sin problema.

Probé a desactivar el antivirus y el firewal y tampoco funciona.

Adjunto el código con el modulo que tiene la conexión y agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Busqué en la web proyectos de creación de servicios y hay montones pero ninguno que acceda a una base de datos.

```
Public Class Service1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        ' Agregue el código aquí para iniciar el servicio. Este método debería poner
        ' en movimiento los elementos para que el servicio pueda funcionar.
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        Timer2.Stop()
        ' Agregue el código aquí para realizar cualquier anulación necesaria para detener el servicio.
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Timer2.Elapsed
        Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\hora.txt")
        sw.WriteLine(Hour(Now) & ":" & Minute(Now) & ":" & Second(Now))
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()


        Try
            conectar()
            Abrir()

        Catch ex As Exception
          Dim sy As New IO.StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Terminó.txt")
            sy.WriteLine("Llegó hasta acá")
            sy.Flush()
            sy.Close()
        End Try

        Dim arancelSecundaria As Decimal
        Dim arancelS As String = "SELECT arancel_importe
                                     FROM arancel
                                     WHERE codigo_nivel = 3"
        Dim comandoArancel As New SqlCommand(arancelS, conexion)
        arancelSecundaria = comandoArancel.ExecuteScalar



        Dim comandoTabla As New SqlCommand("SEL_DeudaTabla", conexion)

        comandoTabla.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Dim adaptadorTabla As New SqlDataAdapter(comandoTabla)
        Dim Tabla As New DataTable

        Try
            adaptadorTabla.Fill(Tabla)

            For Each row As DataRow In Tabla.Rows
                Dim codFam As Integer = row("codigo_familia")
                Dim fechaVenc As Date = row("fecha_vencimiento")
                Dim matricula As Decimal = (Val(row("matricula")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim arancel As Decimal = (Val(row("arancel")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim campamento As Decimal = (Val(row("campamento")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim talleres As Decimal = (Val(row("talleres")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim materiales As Decimal = (Val(row("materiales")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim adicional As Decimal = (Val(row("adicional")) / arancelSecundaria)
                Dim comedor As Decimal = (Val(row("comedor")) / arancelSecundaria)


                If matricula + arancel + campamento + talleres + adicional + comedor <> 0 Then

                    Dim tablaDeuda As String = "INSERT INTO deuda_flia (codigo_familia, periodo_deuda, matricula_deuda, arancel_deuda, 
                                                              campamento_deuda, talleres_deuda, materiales_deuda, 
                                                              adicional_deuda, comedor_deuda)
                                                        VALUES (@codigo_familia, @periodo_deuda, @matricula_deuda, @arancel_deuda, 
                                                              @campamento_deuda, @talleres_deuda, @materiales_deuda, 
                                                              @adicional_deuda, @comedor_deuda)"
                    Dim comandoDeuda As New SqlCommand(tablaDeuda, conexion)

                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codigo_familia", codFam)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodo_deuda", fechaVenc)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricula_deuda", matricula)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@arancel_deuda", arancel)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@campamento_deuda", campamento)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@talleres_deuda", talleres)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@materiales_deuda", materiales)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adicional_deuda", adicional)
                    comandoDeuda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comedor_deuda", comedor)

                    comandoDeuda.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    Dim estadoDeuda As String = "UPDATE familias 
                                                     SET estado_deuda = 'Si'  
                                                     WHERE codigo_familia = " & codFam & ""
                    Dim comandoEstado As New SqlCommand(estadoDeuda, conexion)
                    comandoEstado.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End If

            Next


        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim sy As New IO.StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Terminó.txt")
            sy.WriteLine("Terminamos pibe")
            sy.Flush()


        End Try
        Cerrar()
    End Sub
End Class
```

y el modulo con la conexion:

```
Module ConexionProvi
    Public conexion As New SqlConnection()

    Sub Conectar()

        conexion.ConnectionString = "Data source=NNNNNNNNN; Initial Catalog= nombre_base_de_datos; Integrated security = True"
        Try
            Abrir()

            ' MessageBox.Show("Conexión creada exitosamente", "Conexión a gestión_providencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox("¡NO SE PUDO CONECTAR CON LA BASE DE DATOS!")
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Abrir()
        If conexion.State = 0 Then
            conexion.Open()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub Cerrar()
        If conexion.State = 1 Then
            conexion.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: `Integrated security = True` Estás usando autenticación de windows y el servicio no puede conectar así. La manera más simple, haz un login Sql y cambia la cadena de conexión a ese login.

Comment: Muchas gracias. No tenía idea de eso.

Comment: Hola. Hice un login con autenticación sqlserver como recomendaste y andubo a la perfección. Muchas gracias.